# How to disable varnish cache for wildcard subdomains

Tags: regex, caching, varnish, wildcard-subdomain, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to disable caching in varnish for all subdomains.  Our application allows users to create and manage their own website on a subdomain of our url, but varnish keeps caching their page when they're trying to edit it.

I know the basic format:

```
if (req.url ~ "[code here]") {
    # Don't cache, pass to backend
    return (pass);
}
```

but nothing I've tried seems to work for all subdomains.

Maybe it's a simple regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `req.http.host` for this purpose. And yes, it can be a regex.

```
sub vcl_recv
{
   /* your earlier definitions */
   if( req.http.host ~ 'my.subdomain.example.com' )
   {
        // set the backend first
        set req.backend = localhost;

        return( pass );

    }

    /* your definitions  */
 }
```

In some cases you may need to `return( pipe )`:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/faq/configuration.html

Comment: such as? you can use  `req.http.host ~ '.example.com'` that will catch all subdomains. or you need us to do a regexp for you that will catch subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need this for any subdomain (note this may be an issue if you use www as it may be considered a subdomain) and will match anything before the . in example.com

```
sub vcl_recv {
      if(req.http.host ~ ".*\.example.com") {      
        return( pass );
    }

 }
```